# MatLab Map - Specified Key Type Not Matching Required

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to make a program (for homework) which reads in a file, and then counts the number of times each word is used.  For tackling the issue efficiently, I've decided to map all unique words to keys, and then increment the key value each time the word comes up.

```
function [] = problem2
    file_open = fopen('austen.txt');
    complete_string = textscan(file_open, '%s');

    numel(complete_string{1,1})

    unique_words = unique(complete_string{1,1});
    length(unique_words);
    frequency = zeros(numel(unique_words), 1);

    found_frequency = containers.Map(unique_words, frequency);

    for i=1:numel(complete_string{1,1})
       found_frequency(complete_string{1,1}(i)) = found_frequency(complete_string{1,1}(i))+1; 
    end

    fclose(file_open)
```

Sadly, this code does not work.  When the line comes up to increment, I receive an error stating that "specified key type does not match the type expected for this container", which makes no sense to me - I'm using strings as the keys.  Any ideas as to why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: http://dingo.sbs.arizona.edu/~hammond/ling439-f14/austen.txt

Here's the file which I'm using for this particular script - for anyone if they'd like to reproduce the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the use of Cell type - complete_String{1,1}(i) would actually return a Cell rather than a String (per spec, though).  Wrapped it in char(*) and it worked fine.